# How can I use d3.js to sort a table by different variables?

Tags: javascript, sorting, d3.js

```js
    data = [
      {
        "name": "Dave",
        "dept": "Marketing",
        "region": "South",
        "items": 28
      },
      {
        "name": "Amy",
        "dept": "IT",
        "region": "West",
        "items": 46
      },
      {
        "name": "John",
        "dept": "Sales",
        "region": "North",
        "items": 35
      },
      {
        "name": "Sarah",
        "dept": "Communications",
        "region": "North",
        "items": 13
      }
    ]

    drawTable(data)
    sortTable(data)

    function drawTable(data) {

      // not working
      // when redrawing table, trying to re-initialize sort function
      sortTable(data)

      d3.select('#data-table').remove()

      let table = d3.select('#table').append('div').attr('id', 'data-table')

      let row = table.selectAll('.row')
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'row')

      let grid = row
        .append('div')
        .attr('class', 'grid')

      let name = grid.append('div')
        .attr('class', 'box')
        .html(d => d.name)

      let dept = grid.append('div')
        .attr('class', 'box')
        .html(d => d.dept)

      let region = grid.append('div')
        .attr('class', 'box')
        .html(d => d.region)

      let items = grid.append('div')
        .attr('class', 'box')
        .html(d => d.items)

    }

    function sortTable(data) {
      d3.selectAll(".name,.dept,.region,.items").on('click', function () {
        let sortWhich = d3.select(this).attr("class")
        console.log('sortWhich', sortWhich)

        let tableSort
        if (sortWhich == "name") {
          tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.name, b.name))
        } else if (sortWhich == "dept") {
          tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.dept, b.dept))
        } else if (sortWhich == 'region') {
          tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.region, b.region))
        } else {
          tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.items, b.items))
        }

        // Can I combine the above and pass a variable to a sort function? This is not working:
        // let tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => a.sortWhich - b.sortWhich)

        drawTable(tableSort)
      })
    }
```

```css
html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      margin: 0;
    }

    .grid {
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
      flex-direction: row;
    }

    .grid>div {
      display: flex;
      flex-basis: calc(100%/4 - 28px);
      justify-content: center;
      flex-direction: column;
      padding: 10px;
    }

    .box {
      margin: 0;
    }

    .box {
      color: #000;
      border: .5px solid #ccc;
    }

    .hrbox {
      background-color: #333;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="table">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="box hrbox name">
        <div>name</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box hrbox dept">
        <div>dept</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box hrbox region">
        <div>region</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box hrbox items">
        <div>items</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-table"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

I created a flexbox table using d3.js that pulls json data to populate it.
I want to be able to sort each column by its header row, and I wrote a sort function for that. However, I'm only able to sort one column at a time right now. Then if I refresh the page, I can sort a different column. I want to be able to switch without needing to refresh the page. So- sort by name, then decide to sort by items, then region, to see different views of the data. What am I missing?

I'd appreciate any feedback.

[I'd also like to just have one sort function that I pass a variable to instead of having all those conditionals. I'm not sure if it's possible. (Definitely not my main concern.) But putting it out there]

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the console you'll see that `sortWhich` is always something like `"box hrbox whatever"`, and because of that all conditions will fail and the code will go to the `else` at the bottom.

A simplest solution is using `includes()`:

```
if (sortWhich.includes("name")) etc...
```

Here is your code with that change:

```js
data = [{
    "name": "Dave",
    "dept": "Marketing",
    "region": "South",
    "items": 28
  },
  {
    "name": "Amy",
    "dept": "IT",
    "region": "West",
    "items": 46
  },
  {
    "name": "John",
    "dept": "Sales",
    "region": "North",
    "items": 35
  },
  {
    "name": "Sarah",
    "dept": "Communications",
    "region": "North",
    "items": 13
  }
]

drawTable(data)
sortTable(data)

function drawTable(data) {

  // not working
  // when redrawing table, trying to re-initialize sort function
  sortTable(data)

  d3.select('#data-table').remove()

  let table = d3.select('#table').append('div').attr('id', 'data-table')

  let row = table.selectAll('.row')
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'row')

  let grid = row
    .append('div')
    .attr('class', 'grid')

  let name = grid.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'box')
    .html(d => d.name)

  let dept = grid.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'box')
    .html(d => d.dept)

  let region = grid.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'box')
    .html(d => d.region)

  let items = grid.append('div')
    .attr('class', 'box')
    .html(d => d.items)

}

function sortTable(data) {
  d3.selectAll(".name,.dept,.region,.items").on('click', function() {
    let sortWhich = d3.select(this).attr("class")
    console.log('sortWhich', sortWhich)

    let tableSort
    if (sortWhich.includes("name")) {
      tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.name, b.name))
    } else if (sortWhich.includes("dept")) {
      tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.dept, b.dept))
    } else if (sortWhich.includes('region')) {
      tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.region, b.region))
    } else {
      tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a.items, b.items))
    }

    // Can I combine the above and pass a variable to a sort function? This is not working:
    // let tableSort = data.sort((a, b) => a.sortWhich - b.sortWhich)

    drawTable(tableSort)
  })
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

.grid {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid>div {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: calc(100%/4 - 28px);
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  padding: 10px;
}

.box {
  margin: 0;
}

.box {
  color: #000;
  border: .5px solid #ccc;
}

.hrbox {
  background-color: #333;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v6.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="table">
    <div class="grid">
      <div class="box hrbox name">
        <div>name</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box hrbox dept">
        <div>dept</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box hrbox region">
        <div>region</div>
      </div>
      <div class="box hrbox items">
        <div>items</div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div id="data-table"></div>
  </div>
</body>
```

There are some problems here:

- `sort()` sorts the array in place, no need for that `tableSort` variable
- Removing the elements for painting the table again is **not** idiomatic D3, just use enter/update/exit selections.

Regarding your secondary question, if you had the proper variable names you could just use bracket notation, removing all that `if...else` section:

```
data.sort((a, b) => d3.ascending(a[sortWhich], b[sortWhich]))
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough response! I totally overlooked that I had multiple classes per element.
I also really appreciate your notes on the other parts of my code that I can clean up.
And your answer to my secondary question!
So awesome- thank you again!